# Find the minimum cost matching between arrays of integers

Tags: code-golf, number, array

Consider two sorted arrays of integers \$X\$ and \$Y\$ of size \$m\$ and \$n\$ respectively with \$m < n\$.  For example \$ X = (1,4)\$, \$Y = (2,10,11)\$.

We say that a matching is some way of pairing each element of \$X\$ with an element of \$Y\$ in such a way that no two elements of \$X\$ are paired with the same element of  \$Y\$.  The cost of a matching is just the sum of the absolute values of the differences in the pairs.

For example, with \$X = (7,11)\$, \$Y = (2,10,11)\$ we can make the pairs \$(7,2), (11,10)\$ which then has cost \$5+1 = 6\$.  If we had made the pairs \$(7,10), (11,11)\$ the cost would have been \$3+0 = 3\$.  If we had made the pairs \$(7,11), (11,10)\$ the cost would have been \$4+1 = 5\$.

As another example take \$X = (7,11,14)\$, \$Y = (2,10,11,18)\$. We can make the pairs \$(7,2), (11,10), (14,11)\$ for a cost of \$9\$.  The pairs \$(7,10), (11,11), (14,18)\$ cost \$7\$.

The task is to write code that, given two sorted arrays of integers \$X\$ and \$Y\$, computes a minimum cost matching.

### Test cases

```
[1, 4],      [2, 10, 11]     => [[1, 2], [4, 10]]
[7, 11],     [2, 10, 11]     => [[7, 10], [11, 11]]
[7, 11, 14], [2, 10, 11, 18] => [[7, 10], [11, 11], [14, 18]]
```

Comment: Will X or Y ever have repeated values?

Comment: @Mnemonic No they won't

Comment: To be clear, we return the matching with the minimum cost, not the minimum cost.

Comment: Can we have more examples?

Comment: Can we assume there is only one matching that has minimal cost?

Comment: @dylnan No but you only have to output one of them

Comment: Can we output all of them?

Comment: @dylnan Just one please.

Comment: @Arnauld  They can be positive or negative.

Comment: What output formats are acceptable? For instance, since `X` is fixed, can we output only the choices of elements of `Y`? So in the last example the output would be `10,  11, 18`

Comment: Why did you design this challenge with Y having more elements than X rather than with Y having the same number as X or more?

Comment: @LuisMendo X and Y have already been confirmed as each having no repeats (look up). Also, the no two elements bit just means your pairings are all 1:1 and the example is matching X's 11 to Y's 11.

Comment: @msh210 If they have to same number of elements there is a very simple linear time algorithm,.

Comment: I said same number or more.

Comment: Can we output `[[10, 7], [11, 11]]` instead of `[[7, 10], [11, 11]]`?

Comment: More regarding Erik's comment above - since the inputs are guaranteed to be sorted isn't it enough just to return the elements being chosen from Y?

Comment: @JonathanAllan That's a very good point and I agree.

Answer (score 4):

## [Jelly](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly), <s>15 14 12</s> 11 bytes

```
Œ!ż€IASƊÞḢṁ
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y0rNyan8///oJMWjex41rfF0DD7WdXjewx2LHu5s/P//v5GOoYGOoeF/cyABAA)

- -1 byte thanks to Jonathan Allan
- -1 byte thanks to Mr. Xcoder
- -2 bytes thanks to an anonymous editor

Brute force. Takes input as \$Y\$ then \$X\$.

```
Œ!ż€IASƊÞḢṁ
Œ!                 All permutations of Y.
  ż€               Zip each of the permutations with X.

       ƊÞ          Sort by:
    I              Difference of each pair.
     A             Absolute value.
      S            Sum.
         Ḣ         Take the first matching.
          ṁ        Mold the result like X. Keeps only values up to the length 
                   of X which removes unpaired values from Y.
```

Comment: Would `L}` work in place of `⁹L¤`?

Comment: @Mr.Xcoder Yes, thanks!

Comment: `ÐṂḢ` -> `ÞḢ` to save a byte.

Answer (score 4):

## [Brachylog](https://github.com/JCumin/Brachylog), 16 bytes

```
∧≜I&pᵐz₀.-ᵐȧᵐ+I∧
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##SypKTM6ozMlPN/r//1HH8kedczzVCh5unVD1qKlBTxfIOLEcSGh7AuX@/4@ONtcxNNQxNInViTbSMTQAcyxiY/9HAQA)

#### Explanation

```
∧
 ≜I                   Take an integer I = 0, 1, -1, 2, -2, 3, -3, …
   &pᵐ                Permute each sublist
      z₀.             Zip the sublists together. The result of the zip is the output
         -ᵐȧᵐ         Absolute differences of each pair
             +I       The sum of these differences must be I
               ∧
```

Since we unify `I` to an integer at the very beginning, we try things from small values of `I` to large values of `I`, which means the first time it will succeed will necessarily be for the pairing with smallest absolute differences.

Answer (score 3):

### Haskell, <s>78</s> <s>77</s> 76 bytes

```
import Data.Lists
(argmin(sum.map(abs.uncurry(-))).).(.permutations).map.zip
```

TIO doesn't have `Data.Lists`, so no link.

Basically the same algorithm as seen in [@dylnan's answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/167746/34531).

Edit: -1 byte thanks to @BMO.

Answer (score 2):

## JavaScript (ES7), 121 bytes

Takes the 2 arrays in currying syntax `(x)(y)`.

```javascript
x=>y=>(m=P=(b,[x,...a],s=0,o=[])=>1/x?b.map((v,i)=>P(b.filter(_=>i--),a,s+(x-v)**2,[[x,v],...o])):m<s||(r=o,m=s))(y,x)&&r
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##fYxNasMwEIX3PYVWYSYdy5ExpJSMc4XsxVDs1C4udhSsYBTI3V1Zq1LaDjwY3s/3Wc@1P0/99ZZd3Hu7dLwEru5cwcgnhoZsIK11LeR5R46tIFcmD8dGj/UVYKY@GidodNcPt3aCN676LEOqyT9DyGbcbguykTLLCnKC@Doe/OMBEzsa2SPCnQJuNtNydhfvhlYP7gM6sIZUKaTiIdiClNlFGUkGqjxXdq0UsWLLNRV5@kHYpwH9R9inZUQYk7LfGVGlfGdEvchfjPUrU0OWLw)

Answer (score 2):

## [J](http://jsoftware.com/), 24 bytes

```
[,.[-[:,@:(0{]#~1>])"1-/
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##hYyxCoAgGAZ3n@KjBgv8zT@CQjB6D3GKJFoaGqNe3QKXtrbjDm5L8XAaBhYmeaU9easmW5kzlDePoS6YmlSLQkNGpyUULot4CLHM6w5Gh4gWbMCclSQimbF/5V/mzwA8iPQA)

### Explanation/Demonstration:

A dyadic verb, `x f y`

`-/` finds the differences

```
 7 11 14 -/ 2 10 11 18
 5 _3 _4 _11
 9  1  0  _7
12  4  3  _4
```

`(0{]#~1>])"1` for each row keep only the non-positive values and take the first one:

```
   7 11 14 ([:(0{]#~1>])"1-/) 2 10 11 18
_3 0 _4
```

`[:,@:` flattens the list (to match the shape of the left argument)

`[-` subtract the min. differences from the left argument

```
    7 11 14 ([-[:,@:(0{]#~1>])"1-/) 2 10 11 18
10
11
18
```

`[,.` stitch them to the left argument:

```
   7 11 14 ([,.[-[:,@:(0{]#~1>])"1-/) 2 10 11 18
 7 10
11 11
14 18
```

Answer (score 1):

## [MATL](https://github.com/lmendo/MATL), 16 bytes

```
yn&Y@yy&1ZP&X<Y)
```

Inputs are `X`, then `Y`.

The matching is output with the first values of each pair (that is, `X`) in the first line, and the second values of each pair in the second line.

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y00syfn/vzJPLdKhslLNMCpALcImUvP//2hzBUPDWK5oIwVDAxALAA) Or [verify all test cases](https://tio.run/##y00syflvbKX0vzJPLdKhslLNMCpALcImUvO/QXKEy/9oQx0Fk1iuaCMdBUMDIDYEss0hlBFQBCoAkgBiFIVAbBELAA).

#### Explanation

```
y       % Implicit inputs: X, Y. Duplicate from below
        % STACK: [7 11], [2 10 11], [7 11]
n       % Number of elements
        % STACK: [7 11], [2 10 11], 2
&Y@     % Variations without repetition
        % STACK: [7 11], [2 10; 2 11; 10 2; 10 11; 11 2; 11 10]
yy      % Duplicate top two elements
        % STACK: [7 11], [2 10; ...; 11 10], [7 11], [2 10; ...; 11 10]
&1ZP    % Compute cityblock distance between rows of the two input matrices
        % STACK: [7 11], [2 10;...; 11 10], [6 5 12 3 13 5]
&X<     % Argmin (first index of occurrences of the minimum)
        % STACK: [7 11], [2 10; 2 11; 10 2; 10 11; 11 2; 11 10], 4
Y)      % Row indexing. Implicit display
        % STACK: [7 11], 10 11]
```

Answer (score 1):

## [Octave](https://www.gnu.org/software/octave/), 66 bytes

```matlab
@(X,Y)[X;C([~,r]=min(sum(abs(X-(C=perms(Y)(:,1:numel(X)))),2)),:)]
```

Anonymous function that takes row vectors `X`, `Y` as inputs and outputs a 2-row matrix where each column is a pair of the matching.

[**Try it online!**](https://tio.run/##VYtBCsIwFET3niLL@fANpghKJCD0EikhiyopCKZKY1169fizEgceDG@Yx/U1vlOdnNa6nuF5oOBPPcKHl@jybUZZM8ZLgd@id8@05IKBYNnYec3pDk8S7gRLsU4IhtU@sgodK7MTTKSN6ENrTYv9ybYL/wfhGKl@AQ)

Answer (score 1):

## [Pyth](https://pyth.readthedocs.io), 18 bytes

```
t#h.msaMbm.T,dvz.p
```

[Try it here!](http://pyth.herokuapp.com/?code=t%23h.msaMbm.T%2Cdvz.p&input=%5B2%2C10%2C11%5D%0A%5B7%2C11%5D&debug=0)

Answer (score 1):

## [Pyth](https://github.com/isaacg1/pyth), 16 bytes

```
hosaMNCM*.pQ.cEl
```

Try it online [here](https://pyth.herokuapp.com/?code=hosaMNCM%2A.pQ.cEl&input=%5B7%2C%2011%2C%2014%5D%0A%5B2%2C%2010%2C%2011%2C%2018%5D&debug=0), or verify all test cases at once [here](https://pyth.herokuapp.com/?code=hosaMNCM%2A.pQ.cEl&test_suite=1&test_suite_input=%5B1%2C%204%5D%0A%5B2%2C%2010%2C%2011%5D%0A%5B7%2C%2011%5D%0A%5B2%2C%2010%2C%2011%5D%0A%5B7%2C%2011%2C%2014%5D%0A%5B2%2C%2010%2C%2011%2C%2018%5D&debug=0&input_size=2).

```
hosaMNCM*.pQ.cEl   Implicit: Q=evaluated 1st input, E=evaluated 2nd input
               l   Length of 1st input (trailing Q inferred)
            .cE    All combinations of 2nd input of the above length
         .pQ       All permutations of 1st input
        *          Cartesian product
      CM           Transpose each of the above
 o                 Order the above using:
   aMN               Take the absolute difference of each pair
  s                  ... and take their sum
h                  Take the first element of the sorted list, implicit print
```

Answer (score 1):

## [Jelly](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly), (10?) 12 [bytes](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly/wiki/Code-page)

<sup>10 bytes if just the elements of Y are required (see comments) - not sure if it's allowed by spec yet though (and maybe it shouldn't be since other answers already implement this detail).

This may be achieved [by removing the trailing `⁸ż`](https://tio.run/##y0rNyan8/9/n6ORkh4e7FgYfWnp43qPGHQ93LPr//3@0uY6CoSEQm8T@jzYC0gZQvkUsAA).</sup>

```
Lœc@ạS¥Þ⁸Ḣ⁸ż
```

A dyadic link accepting X on the left and Y on the right.
(`œc⁹L¤ạS¥ÞḢż@` and the 10 byte `œc⁹L¤ạS¥ÞḢ` do the same with Y on the left and X on the right).

**[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y0rNyan8/9/n6ORkh4e7FgYfWnp43qPGHQ93LAKSR/f8//8/2lxHwdAQiE1i/0cbAWkDKN8iFgA)**

#### How?

```
Lœc@ạS¥Þ⁸Ḣ⁸ż - Link: sorted list of integers X, sorted list of integers Y
L            - length
   @         - with swapped arguments:
 œc          -   combinations (chosen as if picked left-to-right
             -      e.g. [2,5,7,9] œc 2 -> [[2,5],[2,7],[2,9],[5,7],[5,9],[7,9]] )
        ⁸    - chain's left argument (to be on right of the following...)
       Þ     -   sort by:
      ¥      -     last two links as a dyad:
    ạ        -       absolute difference (vectorises)
     S       -       sum
         Ḣ   - head (since sorted this is just the first minimal choices from Y)
          ⁸  - chain's left argument
           ż - zip with (the chosen Y elements)
```

Answer (score 1):

## JavaScript (ES7), 100 bytes

New here; any tips/corrections would be appreciated! A previous attempt overlooked complications with sorting an array containing a `NaN` value, so hopefully I haven't missed anything this time.

```
(x,y,q=Infinity)=>y.map((u,j)=>(p=0,s=x.map((t,i)=>(u=y[i+j],p+=(t-u)**2,[t,u])),p)<q&&(q=p,r=s))&&r
```

Expects two arguments as *X*, *Y*, respectively.
[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##dY3BboMwEETvfIVPyE4WJ0SV2kO3934D8sHCUBkR2@Algq@nBg5VWnWlkXbnaXY6/dCxHm2gwnnTrC2ufIYFBvx0rXWWFoEfi7zrwPkEXTp4wCtEnA@PwG7ehEtlz52CcEZOxSROpxtUBJMSAoJ4H/KcDxhgxChEno8rIZdSzilbexd938jef/H2MEWWXS6Mmkis1rGJLIz@YU1jMuJVCexFAdunugErr0mlEht73Vf4nyVt4R@W9KaOPm2MJeud7vfq@KcsBX79fMJF@cTXbw)

Appears to be similar to [@Arnauld's solution](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/167749/81410)

## Explanation

Relies on the fact that given *X*, *Y* are sorted, there exists a solution of
minimum cost matches where if all pairs are arranged to preserve the order of
elements of *X*, all *Y* elements in the arrangement also preserve their order.

```
(x, y, q = Infinity) =>
    y.map((u, j) =>                   // iterate over indices of y
        (
            p=0,
            s=x.map((t, i) => (       // map each element of x to...
                    u = y[i+j],       // an element of y offset by j
                    p += (t-u)**2,    // accumulate the square of the difference
                    [t, u]            // new element of s
                )),
            p
        ) < q                         // if accumulated cost less than previous cost...
                                      // (if p is NaN, any comparison will return false and short circuit)
        && (q=p, r=s)                 // save cost, pair values respectively
    ) && r                            // return lowest-cost pairs
```